# Form_for force user to enter date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I want to do a form that force user to enter date format.
I mean a value by default like DD/MM/YYYY and the user cant't delete the "/", he just could replace the letter.

My form actually work but if an user enter a date with a bad format, some method crash.

This is my form:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for :missions, remote: true, :html => { :role => "form"} do |f| %>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <%= f.date_field :debut, label: "Debut de Mission" %>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use javascript to add a mask to your field. There are plenty of plugins that does the job.
For Example: [jQuery Mask](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)